# How to pass object literal to a filter from the view in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I would like to be able to pass a config object literal to my filter from the view. To do so, I added a second, optional parameter to my filter. I can pass an object literal to the filter, if I define it in the controller, however the code breaks if I try to define an object in the view.

```
$scope.message = 'Hello World';
$scope.configObj = {uppercase: true, exclamationMarks: 5};

<p>OK {{message | shoutFilter}}</p>
<p>OK {{message | shoutFilter:configObj}}</p>
<p>ERROR {{message | shoutFilter:{'exclamationMarks':2}}}</p>
```

You can see a pretty contrived example here: https://jsbin.com/rojekitixo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

I got an error message:

```
Error: [$parse:ueoe] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/$parse/ueoe?p0=message%20%7C%20shoutFilter%3A%7BexclamationMarks%3A2
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes from your object literal.

```
  {exclamationMarks: 2}
```

Comment: I use [`shoutFilter:{exclamationMarks:2}`](https://jsbin.com/pebedilufe/1/edit?html,js,console,output) and I get the same error.

Comment: Not sure what you changed in jsbin.  I made that change and it worked.  Can you revert jsbin to original codes?

Comment: This appears to work:     <p>Passing an object defined in view breaks the filter {{message | shoutFilter:{exclamationMarks:2} }}</p>

Comment: I can pass [shoutFilter:'{exclamationMarks:2}'](https://jsbin.com/losofaqixi/1/edit?html,js,console,output), but this will pass a string to the filter, and not an object literal.

However adding spaces around the object works. That's crazy.

Comment: Must be the way angular parsing curly braces?  There are 3 in a row to end the expression }}}.  I dunno...

Comment: Ok.   ( Where do I accept your edits?)  One last thought - I don't think object literals are quoted.  JSON uses quotes but not obj literals. So maybe angular was rejecting the JSON format for not being valid javascript.

Comment: In my first example I left too many quotes in the JS Bin I linked to, because I tried several things to make it work and unfortunately left too many quotes in my first JSBin link. The real issue was the missing space after the object literal, I don't exactly understand it yet. By the way an object literal's properties can be quoted, open your console and type `var cate = {'doge': 123};
cate.doge;`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the OP in the comments to @brewsky's answer, objects literals passed to filters in templates should be separated by a space from the curly brackets of the whole expression.

For example, this can come in handy with the [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) filter:

```
<button>{{'logout' | translate:{first: ctrl.name, last: ctrl.surname} }}</button>
                                                                     ^
                                                                Here be space
```

Note the space left intentionally between the bracket closing the object literal, `:2}` and the closing bracket of the expression `}}</p>`.